# the file is not a valid app package because it is missing a manifest or block map

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-store-apps

When i try to create a windows store package from my WPF application, i see this error: 
**"the file is not a valid app package because it is missing a manifest or block map"**

I've create an AppxManifest.xml file, but it still doesn't work.

Here's how i use Makeappx.exe and the console output:

```
MakeAppx.exe pack /d .\ /p StoreAppTest1.appx

Microsoft (R) MakeAppx Tool version 1.0.0.0

Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft.  All rights reserved.

The package path (/p) parameter is: "StoreAppTest1.appx"

The content directory (/d) parameter is: ".\"

Enumerating files from directory ".\"

Packing 4 file(s) in ".\" (content directory) to "StoreAppTesame).

MakeAppx : error: The package must contain a manifest.

MakeAppx : error: Package creation failed.

MakeAppx : error: 0x80080203 - The file is not a valid app pa
 missing a manifest or block map.

MakeAppx : error: The specified package format is not valid.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, the AppManifest.xml file must be valid and created according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211476.aspx, if you need just the basic, you can read the quick start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211475.aspx, but the fundamental problem seems to be that WPF applications are not supported in the Windows Store, only Windows Store applications are supported there, so this is a no go.

Comment: You need to register as a company in the windows store. Only companies are allowed to distribute desktop applications through the windows store.